# What companies have opened up their UX content like Mailchimp has done?

Tags: resources

Edit: I'm looking more for the content released by companies not in the operating system/browser world. Sure, there's a ton of stuff out there from Microsoft, Apple, Mozilla, etc. about their UIs and how to build UIs for applications on those platforms, but I think there's more variety and potential novelty in the content released by other companies/apps. A good example in from the answers already submitted was Skype. It's more in line with what I'm looking for. It's more of a "here's 30 pages, in Issuu format, about how we should look", as opposed to, "here's 100pages of HCI guidelines, or a huge vault of developer documentation".

---

I think the content at http://ux.mailchimp.com/patterns and http://mailchimp.com/about/style-guide/ is an excellent way to solve some of the issues described on the landing page of the first link:

> We’re also solving an internal communication problem by documenting
>   and assembling a reference site of our patterns. A common lexicon of
>   code and UI elements benefits us in a few ways:
>
> - We can build consistently and focus on workflows and logic, not web
>     forms and list items
> - We can reuse code instead of roping in a
>     developer
> - We can maintain our code by seeing our patterns in one
>     place, define elements in our application, and keep redundancy to a
>     minimum

I'd like to review more of this type of content. Can anyone suggest other companies that have created and opened up this type content (and done a good job of it)?

Comment: are you looking for design/UX guidelines from established companies?

Comment: You could look at the way almost any CMS handles skins/templates. I have worked with DotNetNuke for years. They have a team dedicated to how to make the skin more flexible for their users.

Answer (score 3):

Some design/UX guidelines from reputable companies:

Google Android:
https://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Apple iOS:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html

Apple OSX:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html

Yahoo.com:
http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/

Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh779072

Comment: These are good, but I wonder if the OP is asking more about internal corporate UX guides made public (vs. guides for platforms made by said companies)

Answer (score 2):

A few more to add.

Skype: http://issuu.com/bondo/docs/skype_brand_book_-_look

Firefox: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/styleguide/identity/firefox/branding/

It would be nice if there was a framework for this, ay?

Comment: You mean a framework for ux.stackexchange? that'd be pretty cool alright

Comment: More like a framework for web brand style guides. Think Bootstrap example page with some brand style guide sprinkled in.